# Ambiguous results when apply 'filter' in Polars groupby context

Tags: python, python-polars

The code below when run multiple times, gives me two different possible results.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
        "y": [4, 5, 8, 7, 9, None, None, None],
        "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
    }

)

xcol = "x"
ycol = "y"
f = pl.col(ycol).is_not_null() & pl.col(xcol).is_not_null()

df.groupby("day").agg(
    (pl.col(xcol) - pl.col(xcol).filter(f).mean()).filter(f).sum().alias("filered_sum")
)
```

The two results returned to me are

```
day filtered_sum
1   null
2   -3.0

day filtered_sum
2   0.0
1   null
```

And, the result I expect to have is

```
day filtered_sum
2   0.0
1   null
```

Any idea what is going on here? What could be the reason for such non-determinate behavior?

Comment: Could you edit your post to explain what your code is supposed to do, and which answer you'd expect to be correct? 
Is this post just an example of a non-determinate behaviour, or something you'd want a more optimized code for, should it exist?

Comment: It's a bug. The second `.filter(f)` seems to be causing it. Using `f = pl.all(pl.col(["x", "y"]).is_not_null())` instead is a workaround.

Comment: Perhaps another way to do it is to drop the nulls before the groupby and left join with the unique days e.g. `df.get_column("day").unique().to_frame().join(` with `df.drop_nulls().groupby("day").agg((pl.col("x") - pl.col("x").mean()).sum())`

Comment: another way to consistently get your expected result would be to put `maintain_order=True` in the `groupby`. I suspect the issue is due to polars not knowing which groups to apply the second filter to?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Nice find. It looks like it also happens with a single filter: `.agg((pl.col("x") - pl.col("x").mean()).filter(f))` - which suggests there is a problem with multiple uses of `pl.col()` inside `.filter()` as using `pl.all(pl.col("x", "y").is_not_null())` doesn't trigger the behaviour.

Comment: looks like this has been fixed on `master` (already!) and will be in the next release

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Does it mean that no maintain_order=True is needed after the fix?

Comment: that's right, shouldn't be needed anymore (once the next release is out, at least)